# Create legend of a line with multiple sections and multiple colors

Tags: plotting, legending

I have this plot. The first three lines are considered as one curve.

[image]

I want to make a legend something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

```
style = {Directive[Thickness[0.03], ColorData[97, 1], 
    CapForm["Round"], Opacity[0.3]], 
       Directive[Thickness[0.03], ColorData[97, 2], CapForm["Round"], 
    Opacity[0.3]], 
       Directive[Thickness[0.03], ColorData[97, 3], CapForm["Round"], 
    Opacity[0.3]], ColorData[97, 4]}; 
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[x, x <= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[2 - x, 1 <= x <= 3/2], 
     ConditionalExpression[2*x^2 - 4, 3/2 <= x <= 2], (2 + x^2)/
   5}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> style]
```

Comment: Perhaps use `Callout`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
style = {Directive[Thickness[0.03], ColorData[97, 1], 
    CapForm["Round"], Opacity[0.3]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.03], ColorData[97, 2], CapForm["Round"], 
    Opacity[0.3]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.03], ColorData[97, 3], CapForm["Round"], 
    Opacity[0.3]], ColorData[97, 4]};
plot = Plot[{ConditionalExpression[x, x <= 1], 
   ConditionalExpression[2 - x, 1 <= x <= 3/2], 
   ConditionalExpression[2*x^2 - 4, 3/2 <= x <= 2], (2 + x^2)/5}, {x, 
   0, 3}, PlotStyle -> style]
```

```
markers1 = 
  Graphics[{{style[[1]], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {1/3, 0}}]}, {style[[2]], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
     Line[{{1/3, 0}, {2/3, 0}}]}, {style[[3]], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
     Line[{{2/3, 0}, {1, 0}}]}}];
markers2 = Graphics[{{style[[4]], Line[{{0, 0}, {.8, 0}}]}}];
Legended[plot, 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[{Opacity[1], Opacity[1]}, {"curve 1", "curve 2"},
    LegendMarkers -> {markers1, markers2}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 20}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, 
       FrameStyle -> Brown] &)], {.3, .8}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I just saw the answer above, but might as well post my attempt.

```
style[t_] := {Directive[Thickness[t], ColorData[97, 1], 
    CapForm["Round"], Opacity[0.3]],
   Directive[Thickness[t], ColorData[97, 2], CapForm["Round"], 
    Opacity[0.3]],
   Directive[Thickness[t], ColorData[97, 3], CapForm["Round"], 
    Opacity[0.3]],
   ColorData[97, 4]
   };
c1 = ConditionalExpression[x, x <= 1];
c2 = ConditionalExpression[2 - x, 1 <= x <= 3/2];
c3 = ConditionalExpression[2*x^2 - 4, 3/2 <= x <= 2];
t = 0.15; (*change to desired thinking for legend only*)
p = Graphics[{{style[t][[1]], Line[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}}]},
    {style[t][[2]], Line[{{.1, 0}, {.2, 0}}]},
    {style[t][[3]], Line[{{.2, 0}, {.3, 0}}]}
    }, ImageSize -> 50, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.1, .1}}
   ];
p2 = Graphics[{{style[t][[4]], Line[{{0, 0}, {.3, 0}}]}
    }, ImageSize -> 50, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.1, .1}}
   ];
Legended[
 Plot[{c1, c2, c3, (2 + x^2)/5}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> style[0.03], 
  ImageSize -> 250, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],
 Placed[Column[{Row[{p, Spacer[5], "Curve 1"}], 
    Row[{p2, Spacer[5], "Curve 2"}]}], Right]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]